# Sometimes MBProgressHUD is not displaying

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, mbprogresshud

I have list of song titles displayed in uitableview along with "Buy" button.when that button is tapped i am showing MBProgressHUD.But sometimes it is not being displayed.also it disables the user-interaction as it is in the below code.

But why it is not displaying the MBProgressHUD sometimes?

Please let me know, Thanks a lot.

> Below is the code

```
-(void) buySong:(UIButton *)button
    {
      self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

      self.navigationController.navigationBar.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

      MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
      hud.labelText = @"Proessing...";
      hud.yOffset = -80;

      UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[button superview] superview];
      NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self tblViewChildrenPoems] indexPathForCell:cell];

      PSSongTags *songTags = [self.songsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      [ [PurchaseViewController sharedPurchaseManager] startPurchase:songTags];

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code may be helped you...

In your .h file import the .

```
 #import "MBProgressHUD.h"
```

the set the delegate .

```
MBProgressHUDDelegate
```

After

```
MBProgressHUD *HUD;
```

in your .m file // Add this code where you want display ...

```
HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];
    HUD.delegate = self;
    HUD.labelText = @"Authorizing...";
    [HUD show:YES];
```

and when your process end use for  hide ..

```
[HUD Hide:YES];
```

and set hide delegate in your m file also..

```
- (void)hudWasHidden:(MBProgressHUD *)hud {
    // Remove HUD from screen when the HUD was hidded
    [HUD removeFromSuperview];
    [HUD release];
    HUD = nil;
}
```

Happy coding...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. and what is the issue in my code,pls let me know

Comment: i think if you are use the navigationController,then MBProgressHUD add in the self.navigationController.view, and in your code you have not set the delegate from your code.